# Show a different view in context menus SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, contextmenu, beta

I'm developing a Mastodon client in SwiftUI and I'd like to allow users to see a preview of a post from the context menu, as many other apps do.

I know I can achieve this in UIKit but I haven't seen how in SwiftUI.

Let's say, for example, that I've got two views: CompactView and ExpandedView.
CompactView is composed of an `Image` and a `Text` with a line limit of 2 so that every other line is hidden. ExpandedView is also composed of an `Image` and a `Text`, but the text's line limit is 20 so that all the post content is shown.

If the user force-touches on the CompactView, I'd like to show ExpandedView in the context menu instead of CompactView. How can I achieve this?

```swift
struct ContentView: some View {

    var body: some View {
        List(0 ..< 5) {
            CompactView()
        }
    }
}

struct CompactView: some View {

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image("profile")
            Text(/*Post content goes here*/)
                .lineLimit(2)
        }
            .contextMenu {
                Button("Report", action: {})
            }
    }
}

struct ExpandedView: some View {

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image("profile")
            Text(/*Post content goes here*/)
                .lineLimit(20)
        }
    }
}
```

My codebase isn't like this, but the approach would be the same I guess.

TL;DR: How can I show a different view when the user force-touches a view in SwiftUI?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you find out how to solve this problem? Currently I am stuck at the exact same topic.

Comment: Hi @FlorianPürschel, unfortunately, I still haven't solved this problem, I'm still stuck. As far as I know, this isn't available *yet* as of Xcode 12 beta 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we need this - [Simple way to implement preview context menu for SwiftUI](https://gist.github.com/SpectralDragon/e1c01388db09752eac790ae23f1d4587)

My content view for example

```
struct ContentView: View {

let deleteAction = UIAction(
title: "Remove rating",
image: UIImage(systemName: "delete.left"),
identifier: nil,
    attributes: UIMenuElement.Attributes.destructive, handler: {_ in print("Foo")})

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .contextMenu(PreviewContextMenu(destination: Text("Destination"), actionProvider: { items in
                return UIMenu(title: "My Menu", children: [deleteAction])
            }))
    }
}}
```

[It's gonna look like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B99PM.png)